# failed to refresh DIV with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, refresh

I want to auto-refresh of certain DIV (darksky widget id="1") in 10 seconds.

I tried many times but failed. please see below and comment what is logical wrong.

here my poor code.

```js
function autoRefresh_sample_div2() {
  var currentLocation2 = window.location;
  $("#1").fadeOut('slow').load(currentLocation2 + ' #1').fadeIn("slow");
}
setInterval('autoRefresh_sample_div2()', 10000); //10 seconds
```

```html
<div class="row col-lg-9">
  <div class="col-lg-1">
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">#</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8 mb-2">
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">Graph</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-2">
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">Weather NOW</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 my-auto">
    <h1 class="display-4 text-center">1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8"><iframe class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9" src="http://naver.com/"></iframe></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 my-auto" id="1">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://darksky.net/widget/default-small/36.2385,127.2047/ca12/en.js?width=100%&height=70&title=Full Forecast&textColor=333333&bgColor=FFFFFF&transparency=false&skyColor=undefined&fontFamily=Default&customFont=&units=ca'></script>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: this is not java tag, it's javascript. 2 different languages

Comment: for a start, you should write `setInterval(autoRefresh_sample_div2, 10000);` (no quotes, no parenthesis)

Comment: @Pierre It will however still work. Bad practice but not the issue here

Comment: I believe the issue is that you try to `load` a div that has a JavaScript embedded. That will not execute the JavaScript again

Comment: @mplungjan the html was so poorly formatted when I wrote the comment...

Comment: *"I tried many times but failed*" - please include what it *actually* did and what you *wanted* it to do.  "it failed" is not enough information.

Comment: *Try* with a non-numeric id, eg `<div id='div1'>` and `#div1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Not recommended to have numeric IDs
2. Your load does not re-execute the iframe script from the weather channel

So I took the weather JS and looked to see what it did.

I added their expected ID to your div and then reload the script with a random value to stop the caching instead of loading your whole page and extracting the div from it.

I tried to attach to the "load" event of the head to fade in, but I use a timeout instead

```js
const weather = new URL('https://darksky.net/widget/default-small/36.2385,127.2047/ca12/en.js?width=100%&height=70&title=Full Forecast&textColor=333333&bgColor=FFFFFF&transparency=false&skyColor=undefined&fontFamily=Default&customFont=&units=ca');

const reloadWeather = () => {
  $('script[id="weather"]').remove();
  weather.searchParams.set("rdn", new Date().getTime());
  $('<script id="weather">').attr('src', weather).appendTo('head');
  setTimeout(() => { $("#customize-script-container").fadeIn("slow") },1000) ;
};

let tId;
$(function() {
  tId = setInterval(() => {
    $("#customize-script-container").fadeOut('slow', reloadWeather)
  }, 10000);
  reloadWeather()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row col-lg-9">
  <div class="col-lg-1">
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">#</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8 mb-2">
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">Graph</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-2">
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">Weather NOW</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 my-auto">
    <h1 class="display-4 text-center">1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 my-auto" id="customize-script-container"></div>

</div>
```

To have more than one weather channel, you have to get an API key, write a server side call with the key OR hack their code.

The JS file contains the following

```
var customContainer = document.getElementById("customize-script-container");
if(customContainer === null)
  document.write("<iframe id='ds_b75d85c2dee419f1bfdd9ce0243df27f' type='text/html' frameborder='0' height='70' width='100%' src='https://darksky.net/widget/default-small/36.2385,127.2047/ca12/en?domain="+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)+"&auth=1581324702_72b56ef770251e4ad0661834a512e6e9&width=100%25&amp;height=70&amp;title=Full%20Forecast&amp;textColor=333333&amp;bgColor=FFFFFF&amp;transparency=false&amp;skyColor=undefined&amp;fontFamily=Default&amp;customFont=&amp;units=ca'></iframe>");
else
  document.getElementById("customize-script-container").innerHTML = "<iframe id='ds_b75d85c2dee419f1bfdd9ce0243df27f' type='text/html' frameborder='0' height='70' width='100%' src='https://darksky.net/widget/default-small/36.2385,127.2047/ca12/en?domain="+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)+"&auth=1581324702_72b56ef770251e4ad0661834a512e6e9&width=100%25&amp;height=70&amp;title=Full%20Forecast&amp;textColor=333333&amp;bgColor=FFFFFF&amp;transparency=false&amp;skyColor=undefined&amp;fontFamily=Default&amp;customFont=&amp;units=ca'></iframe>";
```

That is bad news for us, since they use document.write. I wanted to bypass that but came up with a cooler solution: Just rename each div when updating

```js
let tId, $divs, cnt = 0;

const reloadWeather = () => {
  const $div = $(divs[cnt]);
  $('script[id="weather"]').remove();
  $("#customize-script-container").prop("id", "temp"); // rename the last div
  $div.prop("id", "customize-script-container"); // set the ID expected of the script
  const lat = $div.data("lat");
  const long = $div.data("long");
  let weather = new URL(`https://darksky.net/widget/default-small/${lat},${long}/ca12/en.js?width=100%&height=70&title=Full Forecast&textColor=333333&bgColor=FFFFFF&transparency=false&skyColor=undefined&fontFamily=Default&customFont=&units=ca`);
  weather.searchParams.set("rdn", new Date().getTime());
  $('<script id="weather">').attr('src', weather).appendTo('head');
  setTimeout(() => {
    $div.fadeTo("slow","1")
  }, 1000);
};


$(function() {
  divs = $(".weather");
  tId = setInterval(() => {
    if (cnt >= divs.length) cnt = 0;
    const $div = $(divs[cnt]);
    if ($div) {
      $div.fadeTo("slow",0, function() {
        reloadWeather();
        cnt++;
      })
    } else {
      console.log("div", cnt, "not found")
    }
  }, 10000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-lg-3 my-auto weather" data-lat="36.2385" data-long="127.2047"></div>
<div class="col-lg-3 my-auto weather" data-lat="55.1234" data-long="100.1234"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, mplugjan. can i ask one question more...? If i want to apply this function toward couple of DIV, how can i do that?. shoud Use 'for' loop?

Comment: There is no for loop. Do you have more weather frames you want to change or something else

Comment: yes. I have 5 vertical aligned DIV with different weather URL, actually. How i can apply that?

Comment: @gwanggonJo It just became a little more awesome. Add the divs. Each with a class of weater and each with data attr of lat and long

Comment: I get 5 user logins :/

Comment: yes but this 5 user logins div is nothing. See table head 'weather NOW'. that white blank is weather DIV what i applied from your code. ;D weather widget supposed to placed there, sadly..

Comment: Look in the console. You are not loading jQuery. You need to add to the top of the head `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @mplugjan can i ask one more? To avoid server burden, i adjusted time to 10 minitue each, i have 5 divs, It takes 50 minutes for the whole to load. Can't see five at once when you first come in?

Comment: I’ll look later